# ajax call in jQuery not going to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call in jQuery, but its not going to corresponding controller, am not sure what mistake am doing

```
$.ajax({
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/group/edit/export/download",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                values: savedValues,
                groupId: groupIdent
            },
            success: function(){
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error occurred while saving selecte EMail IDs.");
            },
            complete: function(){

            }
        });
```

and my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/group/edit/export/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void navdbGroupExport(@RequestParam("values[]")String[] values,@RequestParam String groupId) throws Exception 
        {
            System.out.println("we have come to controller"+values);
            System.out.println(groupId);
            int i =0;
            for(String navdb : values)
            {
                excelLibrary.setExcelData(i, 0, navdb,groupId);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

I have tried debugging but the control is not getting transferred to Controller, am confused what to do.

thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors.

Comment: How are you calling this ajax function? Is it by means of a button click or a form submition? And also where did you defined savedValues and groupIdent vairables

Comment: i have made this ajax call in function and function i have called it on button click